# Как сделать плавный переход между вкладками в TabHost?

Tags: android

Как я понимаю, надо переопределить метод TabHost.OnTouchEvent()?

Comment: хочется, чтобы по свайпу ни только переключалась вкладка, а чтобы был плавный переход.

Comment: спросите у @Gorets - он у нас гуру по вкладкам...

Comment: Не изменяй так вопросы, лучше новый задавай или комментов пиши - сложно ориентироваться. Не понятно зачем там что-то переопределять, сделай пример по статье отдельно - там все должно быть плавно

Comment: ок. разобралась уже)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Мы юзали вот это:

[Интерфейс «как в маркете» и кое-что еще](http://habrahabr.ru/post/137021/).